How can I target this type of tooltip (labelled ext:qtip) with CSS?
In the code below, "ext:qtip" creates an annoying tooltip with an enlarged image. Is it possible to target that that tooltip with pure CSS? Nothing I do seems to affect it. I can't touch this code, so really need a CSS-only solution.
<div class="foo" id="bar">
<img src="https://site.com/smallimage.jpg"
    class="pic"
    ext:qtip="
        <div class='tip-image' style='width:600px;'>
        <img src=https:site.com/bigimage.jpg/>
        </div>"
    ext:qwidth="625"
    ext:qclass="bigtooltip"
    id="ext-gen390">
</div>

Here's what I've tried that hasn't worked:
[ext:qtip] { visibility:hidden; }
ext { visibility:hidden; }
#tip-image { visibility:hidden; }
#bigtooltip { visibility:hidden; }
AFAICT the CSS is targeting the correct domain, and the big image is hosted on that domain, etc. So is it possible to target these "ext" tags?

ok, guess it was just a syntax error. I got the tooltip stuff to disappear with
.tip-image {visibility:hidden; position:absolute; }
